# C++ omp no significant improvement

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

I am on MSVC 2019 with the default compiler. The code I am working on is a Mandelbrot image. Relevant bits of my code looks like:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (int y = 0; y < HEIGHT; y++)
    {
       for (int x = 0; x < WIDTH; x++)
           {  
               unsigned int retVal = mandel(x_val + x_incr * x, y_val + y_incr * y);
               mtest.setPixels(x, y,
                        static_cast<unsigned char>(retVal / 6),
                        static_cast<unsigned char>(retVal / 5),
                        static_cast<unsigned char>(retVal / 4));

           } 
     }
```

All of the variables outside of the loop are constexpr, eliminating any dependencies. The mandel function does about 1000 iterations with each call. I would expect the outer loop to run on several threads but my msvc records each run at about 5-6 seconds with or without the omp directive.

Edit (The mandel function):

```
unsigned int mandel(long double x, long double y)
{
    long double z_x = 0;
    long double z_y = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < ITER; i++)
    {
        long double temp = z_x;
        z_x = (z_x * z_x) - (z_y * z_y) + x;
        z_y = 2 * temp * z_y + y;

        if ((z_x * z_x + z_y * z_y) > 4)
            return i;
    }
    return ITER; //ITER is a #define macro
}
```

Comment: is `setPixels` blocking (mutex, stream, GPU resource, etc.)? What is `mtest`? What's the profiler say?

Comment: setPixels has no implementations other than accessing the array and editing it based on the x and y positions. it is a 1d array.

Comment: I didn't use the profiler (not knowing how to do that in msvc). But some eyeballing with and without the pragma directive showed no improvements.

Comment: Does changing the order of the `for` loops help? Also, your `mandel` loop is very inefficient, computing `z_x * z_x` and `z_y * z_y` to compare them to 4 and then re-computing those very same values on the next iteration. On the first iteration, you needlessly square both zeroes.

Comment: I probably could change that, but that would alternate caching stride. I just want to see if omp alone has performance benefits without much external elements involved.

Comment: @SilverFlash Whether or not omp has performance benefits will depend almost entirely on those external elements.

Comment: If instead of OMP you use 8 std threads and let each of them process the rows modulo 8, do you get any performance improvements? Will not explain why, but might give you a comparison baseline.

Comment: I'm not sure if the community MSVC editions have a profiler, but the professional versions have one of the better ones out there, at least for general purpose programs. Its usage is [pretty well documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/?view=vs-2019), too.

Comment: I think there is a profiler in the community version I own. I will try to get an actual performance analysis comparing with std::thread, omp and single-thread. But I suspect its just my rusty system playing tricks on me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mandel function has a vastly differing runtime cost depending on whether the if condition within the loop has been met. As a result, each iteration of your loop will run in a different time. By default omp uses static scheduling *(i.e. break loop into N partitions)*. This is kinda bad, because you don't have a workload that fits static scheduling. See what happens when you use dynamic scheduling.

```cpp
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic, 1)
for (int y = 0; y < HEIGHT; y++)
    {
       for (int x = 0; x < WIDTH; x++)
           {  
               unsigned int retVal = mandel(x_val + x_incr * x, y_val + y_incr * y);
               mtest.setPixels(x, y,
                        static_cast<unsigned char>(retVal / 6),
                        static_cast<unsigned char>(retVal / 5),
                        static_cast<unsigned char>(retVal / 4));

           } 
     }
```

Also time to rule out the really dumb stuff.....

1. Have you included omp.h at least once in your program?
2. Have you enabled omp in the project settings?

IIRC, if you haven't done those two things, omp will be disabled under MSVC.

Comment: I'm dumb, did not know you had to include those headers and enable it via settings. Things have changed since I wrote this code initially, I will test it out when I get the chance.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but please do this:

```
unsigned int mandel(long double x, long double y)
{
    long double z_x = 0;
    long double z_y = 0;
    long double z_x_squared = 0;
    long double z_y_squared = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < ITER; i++)
    {
        long double temp = z_x;
        z_x = z_x_squared - z_y_squared + x;
        z_y = 2 * temp * z_y + y;

        z_x_squared = z_x * z_x;
        z_y_squared = z_y * z_u;

        if ((z_x_squared + z_y_squared) > 4)
            return i;
    }
    return ITER; //ITER is a #define macro
}
```

Also, try inverting the order of your two `for` loops.

Comment: Is the `long double` really necessary?